# $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}{\lfloor x \rfloor + \lfloor x^2 \rfloor + ... + \lfloor x^n \rfloor\over x^n}, 1<x\in \mathbb R^+$

Tags: limits

$$\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}{\lfloor x \rfloor + \lfloor x^2 \rfloor  + ... + \lfloor x^n \rfloor\over x^n}, 1<x\in \mathbb R^+$$
I have a problem solving this limit.Here is my solution. Let x be an integer, then we have:
$$\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}{ x + x^2 + ... + x^n\over x^n} = \lim\limits_{n \to \infty} {(x^n -1)x \over (x - 1) x^n } = \lim\limits_{n \to \infty} {\frac{x^{n+1}}{x^n}-\frac{x}{x^n}\over \frac{x^{n+1}}{x^n} -\frac{x^{n}}{x^n}} = \lim\limits_{n \to \infty} {x - \require{cancel} \cancelto{0}{\frac{x}{x^n}}\over x -1}= {x\over x-1}$$

But I don't know how to solve for non-integer x.

Comment: Can you use [Stolz-Cesaro](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stolz%E2%80%93Ces%C3%A0ro_theorem)?

Comment: yes we can use it

Comment: Hint: $x=\lfloor x\rfloor+r$ with $0\le r<1$ then notice $r^k<1$ so that $\frac{\sum r^k}{x^n}\le \frac n{x^n}$ which goes to $0$ for $x>1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You proved that if $x \in \mathbb{N}_{\geq 2}$ the limit is $\frac{x}{x-1}$, but we can actually prove that for any $x>1$ we have $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \frac{x+\ldots+x^n}{x^n} = \frac{x}{x-1}$.

$x>1$, then $(x+\ldots+x^n) -n\leq\lfloor x \rfloor + \ldots + \lfloor x^n \rfloor \leq x + \ldots +x^n$, which show us that the limit is again $\frac{x}{x-1}$ (Why?)

Comment: With squeeze theorem?

Comment: Yes, using that :)

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Test the cases $0 \le x < 1$ and $x = 1$.

If $x > 1$, use that $\lfloor x \rfloor > x - 1$.

Comment: I forgot that to say  x>1

Comment: Ah, ok, so consider only the second line :-)